# How can I install Node.js version 18 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: node.js, npm

How to install node js version 18 on ubuntu 22.04 ?

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
```

```
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
```

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

I tried these commands many times, but always version v12.22.9
is installed.

To build an app with React, I need Node 14 or higher.

What do you recommend ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I recommend using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm):

**Installing Node Version Manager**

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
```

**Once you have Node Version Manager installed**

1. run in your terminal `nvm install 18` to install version 18 of Node
2. run `nvm use 18` to start using version 18 of Node

Comment: In my case, after running the curl command, it showed not found when I ran nvm commands. Thus, I did source `~/.bashrc`  as mentioned in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04#option-3-installing-node-using-the-node-version-manager). Probably because in my case I was working on a fresh install of Ubuntu

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you.

Comment: as it has no .deb packages and I wanted for my user only, no sudo. This worked great, thx!

Answer (score 12):

#### Install nodejs v20 on Debian and Ubuntu based distributions

**step 1** : Download and import the Nodesource GPG key

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
```

**step 2** : Create deb repository

```
NODE_MAJOR=20
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

optional: here we are installing nodejs **v20** but if you want to install **v18** change `NODE_MAJOR=18` in above command. Similarly if you want to install nodejs **v16** then change `NODE_MAJOR=16`.

**step 3** : Run Update and Install

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```

congratulations you just installed nodejs

##### To uninstall nodejs

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs &&\
rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list &&\
rm -r /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
```

Answer (score 7):

**Please follow these step sequentially:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install -y curl

curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

**After finish check node version:**

```
node --version
```

Comment: Its deprecated right now

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Despite the alarmist warning of deprecation, Node 18 is supported until April 2025. The software I use recommends 18 so it's the natural choice. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: The solution is very short, clean and no extra packages needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Trying to experiment with bun on a new project. Using an Linux VM and this is by far the Simplest answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried those same steps, and they also didn't work for me.  What you need to do is to remove the old version of nodejs first and then autoremove any lingering packages.

```
sudo apt purge nodejs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install nodejs
```

The first line gets rid of the nodeJS v12. The second gets rid of packages that it required and are no longer needed, and which get in the way of installing the new nodejs.

Finally: assuming that you have the PPA from nodesource, you can install nodejs version 18.